# How to run XFCE with no background

Tags: xfce

I'm running XFCE remotely via lightDB with xdcmp enabled.

How do I disable the desktop background, (preferably for remote sessions only)?

Note if I select Menu->Settings->Desktop and select Background Image:none I still get a solid background. This is not good enough. Remember X is a network protocol, I need to client the local desktop with remote applications over the top. When accessing remotely I only require the panel and the window-manager.

Comment: I think this s a function of your X server (on the local machine) rather than the X client window manager. What are you using?

Comment: The point is that the desktop background is essential just a special client 'window' so the server needs to recognise it and discard it.

Answer (score 2):

```
xfdesktop --quit
```

and save the session.

Answer (score 0):

1) it's not an Xserver function, as even running rootless the window manager paints a background.
2) Setting the background to "Transparent" results in a black backdrop. Not Transparent.
3) One can successfully disable the desktop icons and context menu. But the background remains.

Comment: I get neat glitch art looking desktop if I set the background to "transparent". It's probably GPU+driver dependent